# Git reset not changing workspace

Tags: git, restore, cloud9-ide, disaster-recovery

I would firstly like to apologise for my naivety but I am still very new to this and I'm in need of some help!

I've really done a number on my project and am trying to revert to a previous commit, in which the site works fine and all my tests pass. I have tried git reset --hard (commit#), git checkout, plus a few others. Each time the console tells me that the HEAD has changed to the right commit, however my workspace is still exactly the same as I left it.

*How can I revert back to the way the workspace was originally, so that all my files are removed/updated to their previous state?*

Thank you so much for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I have worked it out! I needed to do a git clean to remove the untracked files and directories from the workspace.